# HTML input field returns blank despite having value

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

It's really strange and puzzling me why is it returning blank despite having value. Am I missing something silly?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another element with the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to test if there any duplicate Ids on your DOM

```
    $('[id]').each(function(){
         var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
         if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
             console.warn('Duplicate ID: #'+this.id);
    });
```

The selector for Jquery ID only take the first occurrence.